# How do I create an iterator of lines from a file that have been split into pieces?

Tags: rust, iterator

I have a file that I need to read line-by-line and break into two sentences separated by a "=". I am trying to use iterators, but I can't find how to use it properly within `split`. The documentation says that `std::str::Split` implements the trait, but I'm still clueless how to use it.

```
use std::{
    fs::File,
    io::{prelude::*, BufReader},
};

fn example(path: &str) {
    for line in BufReader::new(File::open(path).expect("Failed at opening file.")).lines() {
        let words = line.unwrap().split("="); //need to make this an iterable
    }
}
```

How can I use a trait I know is already implemented into something like split?

Comment: `.collect()` into an iterable of your choice. See the [examples](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#examples-26).

Comment: Do you mean to try "line.unwrap().split("=").collect()"? if so, I've already did and when I try to ".next()" it gives an error saying "cannot infer type" to words

Comment: The result of `split` is iterable. but you likely have lifetime problems because `line.unwrap()` is a temporary, have you tried `let words = line.unwrap(); let words = words.split("=");`?

Comment: See https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=11337f7e299987d284e031cf9679f875.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As [@Mateen commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53938867/iterators-in-rust#comment94717614_53938867), `split` already returns an iterable. To fix the lifetime problems, save the value returned by `unwrap()` into a variable before calling `split`.

I'll try to explain the lifetime issue here.

First it really helps to look at the function signatures.

```
pub fn unwrap(self) -> T
```

```
pub fn split<'a, P: Pattern<'a>>(&'a self, pat: P) -> Split<'a, P>
```

`unwrap` is pretty simple, it takes ownership of itself and returns the inner value.

`split` looks scary, but it's not too difficult, `'a` is just a name for the lifetime, and it just states how long the return value can be used for. In this case it means that both the input arguments must live at least as long as the return value.

```
//                   Takes by reference, no ownership change
//                               v
pub fn split<'a, P: Pattern<'a>>(&'a self, pat: P) -> Split<'a, P>
//           ^              ^      ^                         ^
//           |              |--|---|                         |
// This just declares a name.  |                             |
//                             |                             |
//           Both of these values must last longer than -----|
```

This is because `split` doesn't copy any of the string, it just points to the position on the original string where the split takes place. If the original string for some reason was dropped, the `Split` will not point to invalid data.

A variable's lifetime (unless the ownership is passed to something else) lasts till it is out of scope, this is either at the closing `}` if it is named (e.g. with `let`) or it is at the end of line / `;`

That's why there is a lifetime problem in your code:

```
for line in std::io::BufReader::new(std::fs::File::open(path).expect("Failed at opening file.")).lines() {
    let words = line
        .unwrap() // <--- Unwrap consumes `line`, `line` can not be used after calling unwrap(),
        .split("=") // Passed unwrap()'s output to split as a reference
        ; //<-- end of line, unwrap()'s output is dropped due to it not being saved to a variable, the result of split now points to nothing, so the compiler complains.
}
```

### Solutions

Saving the return value of `unwrap()`

```
for line in std::io::BufReader::new(std::fs::File::open("abc").expect("Failed at opening file.")).lines() {
    let words = line.unwrap();
    let words_split = words.split("=");
} // <--- `word`'s lifetime ends here, but there is no lifetime issues since `words_split` also ends here.
```

You can rename `words_split` to `words` to shadow the original variable to not clutter variable names if you want, this also doesn't cause an issue since shadowed variables are not dropped immediately, but at the end of its original scope.

**Or**

Rather than having a iterator of type `str`, all of which are just fancy pointers to the original string, you can copy each slice out to it's own string, removing the reliance on keeping the original string in scope.

There is almost certainly no reason to do this in your case, since copying each slice takes more processing power and more memory, but rust gives you this control.

```
let words = line
    .unwrap()
    .split("=")
    .map(|piece|
        piece.to_owned() // <--- This copies all the characters in the str into it's own String.
    ).collect::<Vec<String>>()
    ; // <--- unwrap()'s output dropped here, but it doesn't matter since the pieces no longer points to the original line string.

let words_iterator = words.iter();
```

`collect` gives you the error `cannot infer type` because you didn't state what you wanted to collect into, either use the turbofish syntax above, or state it on `words` i.e. `let words: Vec<String> = ...`

You have to call `collect` because `map` doesn't do anything unless you use it, but that's out of the scope of this answer.